# Message box hooking in c problems

Tags: c, messagebox, event-hooking

Hello ive started to use hooking in c and i wanted to make a program that does a message box
hook,and im new to hooking but after a lot of reading ive understood enough to make a program that creates a window and does a hook, but my problem is that im unable to see the window

any help would be appreciated
here is the fallowing code:

```
static HHOOK hMsgBoxHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName =  L"Csam";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"myWindowClass",
        L"The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when creating your window? You should, and `GetLastError` should give a specific reason why.

Comment: Any reason you're playing with archaic technologies like message box hooking?  It strikes me as kind of like writing a DOS TSR ;)

Comment: Please realize that there's a code formatting tool. All you have to do is paste in your code, highlight it, and click the formatter.

Comment: @paulsm4 Perhaps he's just using a message box hook as an example to learn about hooking in general.

Answer (score 1):

The class name you've registered your class with does not match the one you use to create your window, and the one you use to create your window is not an existing system class. Therefore, `CreateWindowEx` has no idea what to base your window on.

Thus, you will get the error messagebox, and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS` when called. Always use the appropriate error tools if you have a problem.